# Тире, двоеточие, запятая, точка?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, двоеточие

> Команда Яны заняла первое место среди пятидесяти сильнейших сборных
> России. Так Яна подтвердила свой разряд и перешла на следующую ступень
> **(?)** теперь она готовится к получению звания мастера спорта.

**Что здесь лучше поставить?** У автора стоит тире. Это не ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Так Яна подтвердила свой разряд и перешла на следующую ступень — теперь она готовится к получению звания мастера спорта.*

Запятая здесь не подходит, так как между простыми предложениями есть
связь, это не просто перечисление. Точка тоже будет обрывать эту связь. Можно поставить двоеточие. А постановка тире не ошибка.

> 5. Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с пояснительными отношениями: *Авторов этих писем волновали разные проблемы, но объединяло одно (: —) все они ждали от газеты конкретной и действенной помощи; Всех интересовал только один вопрос (: —) как поскорее выпутаться из создавшегося положения*...
>
> В заключение можно указать, что в «конкурентной борьбе» двоеточия с тире «победителем» нередко выходит тире. Это явление отмечается многими исследователями, которые считают, что «в целом тире — знак более свободный, заходящий и во владения двоеточия» и что «выявляется тенденция к вытеснению в ряде случаев двоеточия знаком тире».

Источник: [*ДВОЕТОЧИЕ — ТИРЕ*](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189) (справочник Розенталя).

Comment: @Катперкат Вы пытались задать вопрос о запятой в теле самого ответа, то есть вошли в "править". Надо было просто спросить здесь, в комментариях. // Нет, запятая там не нужна, так как союзом "и" соединены два однородных придаточных предложения, относящихся к главному предложению "которые считают".