# Тире или двоеточие? Или двоеточие и тире интонационное?

Tags: пунктуация

**1.**

> Четвероклассники перешли на новую ступень – теперь они пятиклассники.

У автора - такие знаки.

**2.**

Можно двоеточие поставить вместо тире?

> Четвероклассники перешли на новую ступень: теперь они пятиклассники.

**3.**

Можно поставить двоеточие и интонационное тире?

> Четвероклассники перешли на новую ступень: теперь они - пятиклассники.

Какой вариант лучше?

Comment: Вы уже задавали [практически такой же вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471068/Тире-двоеточие-запятая-точка). Какой вариант лучше, решает автор, в зависимости от расставленных акцентов. Интонационное тире может иметь место после подлежащего-местоимения. Но дело не в этом. Что это за предложение? Извините, оно мне кажется каким-то искусственным, даже нелогичным. Ученики либо четвероклассники, либо пятиклассники. Весь смысл выражается следующим образом: *ученики перешли из начальной школы в среднее звено*, ну или что-то подобное.

Comment: Понятно. Т. е. первый вариант лучше! Вы ещё помните вопросы!? Я уже забыла :)

Comment: Двоеточие в таких случаях тоже уместно. Интонационное тире, на мой взгляд, здесь лишнее (ну, только если в разговорной речи присутствует явная пауза и логическое ударение на "тепЕрь они"). Но опять же: где это предложение может использоваться? Откуда оно? Думаю, его следует кардинально изменить.

Comment: Спасибо большое, поняла! Да это школа ведёт свою страничку в соцсети. Там моя подруга работает учительницей. Я ингода захожу на страничку эту. А потом люблю ей предъявить претензию. Она злится, а мне смешно. Так и живём...